# How to feed a monadic value to another monad?

Tags: haskell

Let's I have a

`F1 :: K String`

`F2 :: L ()`

How do I call F1 from F2?

Both K and L are Moands. So I am looking for something like

`( a -> L b) -> K a -> L b`

Hoogle search results in
`foldMapM :: (Monad m, Monoid w, Foldable t) => (a -> m w) -> t a -> m w`

which matches what I want sort of as in `t` isn't foldable in my case.

Comment: There is no way to do that, in general. For example, you can't easily pass from `m a` to `Identity a`, otherwise you could craft a function `m a -> a`, and we don't want to have that for every monad `m` (and in particular, `IO`).

Comment: oh makes sense, thanks

Comment: It's not possible in general, but if you have a more specific example then maybe we can solve that.

Comment: When we have to "change monad" we sometimes use a specific type class for that to selectively allow the change. For instance the `MonadIO` class is for those monads `m` allowing a conversion `liftIO :: IO a -> m a`, making it possible to "run IO" inside `m`. This isn't possible for all monads, but when it's possible we can mark the monad as a `MonadIO` one. You can use the same techniques for any other monad -- but you will still have to define the conversion case by case, since there is no general way to proceed.

Comment: I could also maybe make a new monad of monads? Combining K and L in a new monad X and then achieve what I am trying to do? Is this a sound approach?